# No me detecta un import en java

Tags: java

Necesito reconocer el idioma de un documento a través de Tika. A la hora de ejecutar este codigo:

```
import org.apache.tika.language.LanguageIdentifier;
```

Me salta el siguiente error:

```
P1_Tika.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.tika.language.LanguageIdentifier;
                               ^
  symbol:   class LanguageIdentifier
  location: package org.apache.tika.language
1 error
```

Comment: ¿Está correctamente ubicado el `import`? ¿Estás guardando los cambios antes de ejecutar el código?

Comment: Probablemente no tengas esa dependencia incluida en tu proyecto. Dinos qué herramienta usas para incluir las dependencias y si es posible agrega la parte del código en que has incluido esa biblioteca en tu proyecto. O dinos si incluiste el `.jar` directamente y dónde lo incluiste.

Comment: Y qué versión del jar tienes